# ng-click triggered unexpectedly by pressing Enter key in IE8

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

I have a simple ng-click button nested inside ng-repeat and there're no `<form>` in current page.

```
<tr ng-repeat="product in catalog | limitTo: total track by $index" ng-class="{highlight: product==selected}">
    <td class="highlight-hide">
        <div ng-if="canDoSelfOrdering">
            <button class="btn btn-mini" ng-click="callPricing(product)">Price & Order</button>
        </div>
    </td>
    <!-- other td -->
</tr>
```

when the catalog array updated and user pressed ENTER without focus on any inputs. 
the last button element `ng-click="callPricing(product)"` trigger unintentionally.

i tried watch document.activeElement before hitting Enter key it's `<body>`

How to prevent this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Internet Explorer [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534696(v=vs.85).aspx) says that in IE8 Standards mode, the default button value is submit.

> If the ENTER key is pressed while a user is viewing a form that
>   contains a Submit button, the form is submitted.

Although you do not have any forms to submit, i guess IE8 does not check that. Just try writing your button type as **button** explicitly .

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-mini" ng-click="callPricing(product)">Price & Order</button>
```

Comment: FYI - Changing the button type to 'button' will prevent from validation

Comment: consider using $setSubmitted();